# Formatting Serialized JSON With Code-First Entity Framework

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, ef-code-first

I'm using a `Web-API GET` to return JSON for a Report.

The `GET` method returns a simple `db.Reports.ToList();`

This is the dump of the data I retrieve

```
{
        "Project": {
            "Location": {
                "LocationId": 7,
                "Description": "New York"
            },
            "Department": {
                "DepartmentId": 7,
                "Description": "Engineering"
            },
            "ProjectId": 7,
            "Description": "Project_3",
            "LocationId": 7,
            "DepartmentId": 7
        },
        "Person": {
            "Email": "email@gmail.com",
            "FirstName": "John",
            "LastName": "Doe",
            "IsActive": true
        },
        "StatusCode": {
            "StatusId": 8,
            "Description": "Accepted"
        },
        "ReportId": "d4cddb3f-ea6a-4b0a-9820-19bd8ee43b3a",
        "Description": "Report 3",
        "RoundTrip": 45.88,
        "IsBillable": true,
        "StartDate": "2013-06-27T00:00:00",
        "EndDate": "2013-06-27T14:36:32.467",
        "TimeUpdated": "AAAAAAAAJxM="
    }, ... 
}
```

This is the related Report declaration:

```
public class Report
{
    public Guid ReportId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double RoundTrip { get; set; }
    public bool IsBillable { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }

    public byte[] TimeUpdated { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

    public virtual StatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
}
```

In this situation, I'd really like to just have the Ids of the various objects contained in the `Report` class.  For example, I'd really just like to see:

```
    "Project": 7,
    "Location": 7,
    "Department": 7,
    "Person": "email@gmail.com",
    "StatusCode": 8,
    "ReportId": "d4cddb3f-ea6a-4b0a-9820-19bd8ee43b3a",
    "Description": "Report 3",
    "RoundTrip": 45.88,
    "IsBillable": true,
    "StartDate": "2013-06-27T00:00:00",
    "EndDate": "2013-06-27T14:36:32.467",
    "TimeUpdated": "AAAAAAAAJxM="
```

1. Is there a relatively easy way to go about doing this, or would it be in my better interests to just further parse the result I'm seeing already?
2. Why does EF by default create these objects within the JSON rather than just the foreign keys?

Comment: I would use LINQ to project the new json from the old one. That or create another class and write a custom converter. I'd make my choice based on how much you're going to use the result throughout your code base. There is no simple way to change the json like that (aside from changing the API of course).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do without specifically creating a new class. In your `ApiController`, if you are using the typed return type (in favor of an `HttpResponseMessage`), change the List type to `IEnumerable<object>` and return:

```
return db.Reports.Select(r => new {
    Project = r.ProjectId;
    Location = r.Location.LocationId;
    Department = r.Department.DepartmentId;
    Person = r.Person.Email;
    StatusCode = r.StatusCode.StatusId;
    Description: r.Description
    RoundTrip: r.RoundTrip
    IsBillable: r.IsBillable,
    StartDate: r.StartDate,
    EndDate: r.EndDate
    TimeUpdated: r.TimeUpdated
});

// Or if you're using HttpResponseMessage
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Ok, 
    db.Reports.Select(r => new {
        Project = r.ProjectId;
        Location = r.Location.LocationId;
        Department = r.Department.DepartmentId;
        Person = r.Person.Email;
        StatusCode = r.StatusCode.StatusId;
        Description: r.Description
        RoundTrip: r.RoundTrip
        IsBillable: r.IsBillable,
        StartDate: r.StartDate,
        EndDate: r.EndDate
        TimeUpdated: r.TimeUpdated
    }));
```

The default Json serializer (Newtonsoft's Json.Net) is smart enough to serialize anonymous object. The only unknown in the code above is the behaviour of the `TimeUpdated` member as it's a byte array. You may have to adjust the assignment.

Comment: Hey Simon, thanks for the advice. I hadn't thought about just returning generic objects rather than a Report object so I was trying to force a cast which was unnecessary.  I'm going to accept this answer even though Cameron's is also correct because this way serves exactly what I'm after without creating excessive markup.

Comment: +1 This is a great solution. I hadn't thought of this either. I'll keep this way in mind when returning JSON in my APIs in the future.

Comment: This is creating a new class, it's just anonymous. At compile time the C# compiler creates a class definition like any other with some arbitrary name. If you're going to use the returned objects use is widespread explicitly defining the class is definitely better.

Comment: That is correct. Just syntactic sugar and yes, if it is used elsewhere, define de class. But it should be constructed using the object initializer syntax for EF to load only required properties

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend making a model for displaying the JSON as you want it to be displayed. This would be the easiest option.

Something like this should work:

```
public class ReportSimple
{
    public Guid ReportId { get; set; }
    public int Project { get; set; }
    public int Location { get; set; } 
    public int Department { get; set; }
    public string Person { get; set; }
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double RoundTrip { get; set; }
    public bool IsBillable { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public byte[] TimeUpdated { get; set; }

    public ReportSimple(Project project, Person person, StatusCode statusCode)
    {
        Project = project.ProjectId;
        Location = project.Location.LocationId;
        Department = project.Department.DepartmentId;
        Person = person.Email;
        StatusCode = statusCode.StatusId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give a quick example relative to the above?

Comment: Should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal You are correct. I'm writing up some example class.

Comment: I just updated my answer with a sample model. It may need some tweaking to fit your other models, but it should get you started.

Comment: Thanks Cameron, I +1'd you for a viable solution, although I think Simon's answer serves my purpose better since it prevents me from creating all of this redundant markup.

Comment: To add one more thing to Cameron's answer, the problem is if you do: `db.Reports.Select(r =­> new ReportSimple(r.Project, r.Person, r.StatusCode)).ToList()` Entity Framework will materialize the result completely before passing it to `ReportSimple` constructor because it cannot inspect the constructor's code and efficiently decide if he need a property or not. It will essentialy take everything from the database. To make the matter worst, `project.Department.DepartmentId` will result in a new query for every `ReportSimple` unless it is explicitely included if Lazy Loading is enabled